# Zoom Web SDK: you need go to setting enable CC & LT feature type: "INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES"

Tags: zoom-sdk

I'm building a web application that includes Zoom SDK for web, after create and join a meeting I get this error and my browser show black screen:

[image]

I've found the same issue was asked on zoom developer forum:
https://devforum.zoom.us/t/websdk-2-0-1-component-view-unable-to-leave-meeting/60072

But there is no answer to that. How can I resolve this issue? I'm using latest version of Chrome on latest macOS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is referencing the **Closed Caption** and **Live Translation** settings in your Zoom account. You have to login into your zoom account that's associated with your `.join()`'s config options and enable these 2 settings.

You can find information on how to enable them in the zoom docs here: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/6643133682957-Enabling-and-configuring-translated-captions